# Export .sqlite using by Navicat Premium

Tags: database, sqlite, export, navicat

After some changes I want to export database in .sqlite format.
How to export .sqlite format using by Navicat Premium?

Answer (score 1):

How about right-click the connection and select "Connection Information". The value of "Database File" is the location of your sqlite database file. Just copy this file as a backup.